# using HTTP in angular 2,3.1

Tags: javascript, html, http, angular

I am following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0RIrdFfy9t4) tutorial on using http calls in Angular2 and at 4:10secs i hit an issue, he put in a  insertion to point to http in his index.html. It points to `node_mules\angular2\bundles\http.dev.js angular2` ...which i dont have.

I have an @angular folder with http stuff in it but not same files.

I am using Angular2.3.1, see my package.json entry....

```
{
  "name": "myProject",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\" --project src/tsconfig.json --type-check && tslint \"e2e/**/*.ts\" --project e2e/tsconfig.json --type-check",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false",
    "e2e": "protractor"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/core": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^2.0.0-beta.4",
    "@angular/forms": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/http": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/router": "^3.3.1",
```

How do i set myself up to use http?

Answer (score 0):

you're following out-date tutorial, your package.json already include `@angular/http`, just use this in your app

please following official document site for more tutorials

- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt6.html
- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html
- https://scotch.io/tutorials/angular-2-http-requests-with-observables

Comment: Thx, these docs are all predicated on this 'heros' example. I have a Loopback service running on port 3000. Is there a simplier, basic guide to hitting a rest API over HTTP?